# Determinant of the conormal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $Y$ be a smooth submanifold of codimension $r$ in a complex manifold $X$. By virtue of the adjunction formula, we always have the isomorphism
$$K_Y\simeq (K_X\otimes \det N_Y){\,|\,}_Y.$$

Recall that in the case where $r=1$, i.e., $Y$ is an effective divisor, one gets
$$N_Y\simeq \mathcal O(Y){\,|\,}_Y.$$
And thus
$$N_Y^*\simeq \mathcal O(-Y){\,|\,}_Y\subseteq \mathcal O_Y$$
where $\iota:Y\hookrightarrow X$ is the natural inclusion.

Here is my question:
can one give a criterion (or, provide some examples) to guarantee that the following inclusion holds **(in the case where $r\geq 2$)**?

$$\det N_Y^*\subseteq\mathcal O_Y.$$

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I have corrected the question, thanks the comments of [abx](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441904/determinant-of-the-conormal-bundle#comment1140228_441904) and [Jason Starr](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441904/determinant-of-the-conormal-bundle#comment1140230_441904)!

Comment: Don't you want $\ \det N^*_Y\subset \mathscr{O}_Y$? This is what we have for $r=1$.

Comment: The pullback to $Y$ of the natural inclusion $\mathcal{O}(-Y)\hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ is a zero homomorphism.  So you do not have any (natural) inclusion of $N_Y^*$ into $\iota^*\mathcal{O}_X$, not even in codimension $1$.

Comment: Dear @abx, you are right! I have modified the question. The case where $r\geq 2$ is surely I want to ask.

Comment: Dear @JasonStarr, thanks for your correction! I have corrected the question.

Comment: One case where you have such an inclusion is when $X$ is a compact homogeneous manifold: then $T_X$ is globally generated, hence so are $N_Y$ and $\det N_Y$, so picking a section of $\det N_Y$ gives an injection $\det N_Y^*\hookrightarrow \mathscr{O}_Y$ (non canonical, as Jason points out).

Comment: I feel like I heard Winkelmann and Campana talk about some other cases related to Gromov's h-principle.  Maybe these are cases of compact homogeneous manifolds . . .

Comment: TeX notes: $\det N_Y$ `\det N_Y` spaces automatically, avoiding the need for manual spacing in `\text{det } N_Y`. For *ad hoc* operators, you can use `\operatorname`, like `\operatorname{det}` if `\det` weren't already defined. In $\mathcal O(Y)\,|\,_Y$ `\mathcal O(Y)\,|\,_Y`, the subscript attaches to the thin space, not to the vertical bar. The vertical alignment in `\mathcal O(Y)|_Y` is slightly different (side by side: $\vphantom{\,}_Y\vphantom|_Y$). To keep the thin space, you can use $\mathcal O(Y){\,|\,}_Y$ `\mathcal O(Y){\,|\,}_Y`. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Hi @abx, thanks for this criterion. Here is my attempts, please point out any possible mistakes. Since $T_X$ is globally generated, we have $$\bigoplus_i \mathcal O_X \twoheadrightarrow T_X,$$ the pull back operator gives then $$\bigoplus_i \mathcal O_Y \twoheadrightarrow {T_X}|_Y\twoheadrightarrow N_Y.$$ Thus $\operatorname{det} N_Y$ is also globally generated. Selecting a section of $\operatorname{det} N_Y$ gives the desired non-canonical injection.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Ok thanks @abx, so in general the inclusion should fail, right? Can you provide some examples illustrating it? Thanks..

Comment: There are many! A typical example: blow up a point in a surface, you get a rational curve $E$ with $E^2=-1$, hence $N^*_E=\mathscr{O}_E(1)$, which of course has no nontrivial map to $\mathscr{O}_E$.

Comment: Dear @abx, nice example! Thanks a lot!